# How to make 3 column nested list to have only inner gutter (no outside margins)?

Tags: html, css, grid, less, nested-lists

I have a slight problem with lining my nested list with everything else.
I use semantic.gs grid for a site: http://grrr.dontmeshwithus.com/
As you can see, the nested list on the bottom doesn't line up with the black line above or the div "slideshow". There's a small gap on both left and right sides of the outer lists. You can see the problem more clearly by resizing your browser window.

Are there any tricks or ways of dealing with this? The only way I found I could get rid of the gap was by using CSS3 columns, but they don't work cross-browser.. is there a way to make them work cross-browser? Or is there another way to give the list items only inner margin? Or should I just use CSS3 columns and make a fallback for IE..?

HTML:

```
<article id="memberContainer">
    <ul id="memberList">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
    </ul>
 </article>
```

CSS(/LESS):

```
 @columns: 12;
 @column-width: 81;
 @gutter-width: 19;
 @total-width: 100%;

    #memberContainer {
    .border;
    ul#memberList {
      .row(9);
      li {
        .column(3,9);
        margin-top: 1em;
      }
    }
  }
```

The semantic.gs grid that I'm using can be found here:
https://github.com/twigkit/semantic.gs/blob/master/stylesheets/less/grid.less

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can always try the :first-of-type and :last-of-type css3 selectors.  This should provide you with access to the first and last li element to remove its margin

something like this (in less)

```
ul#memberList {
    li{
        &:first-of-type, &:last-of-type{
             margin-left:0; 
             margin-right:0;
        }
    }
}
```

ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo
last of type is just beneath it.

edit: since you are rending a wrapped list, you can only do this if you know up front the number of elements per row.  You can use the nth-child http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo or nth-of-type http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo selectors.

Something like

```
ul#memberList {
    li{
        &:nth-of-type(3n){
             margin-left:0; 
             margin-right:0;
        }
    }
}
```

should take care of your need.

Comment: CSS3 selectors are slow. If you have a 2.1 selector that can be used, use it instead, like `first-child` and `last-child`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it doesn't work. 
See my reply for the other comment.

Comment: Admittedly, I didn't look at your example.  What you are doing is rendering a wrapped list, and CSS does not have a way of handling this (it isnt aware of the location of items on the page, only within the markup).  However, if you have only three (3) items per list, you can remove the outer margin from every third item by using :nth-child(3n)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `:first-child` and `:last-child`(http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html)

I think it would be something like this:

```
ul#memberList {
    li{
        &:first-child, &:last-child{
             margin-left:0; 
             margin-right:0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work unfortunately.
This only removes the margin from the first and the last list items. This is not what I am after, because I have 3 columns and more than 3 list items. What I am trying to get is to have only inner margins for the list items, if you know what I mean. The list margins and width are fluid, so browsers render the widths (for example 0.7916666666666667%) differently, resulting in uneven grid.

Any more ideas?